# Compare a string which has a param

Tags: c#, regex, csv, string.format

I am reading in a header from a file which has time fields for example `Time (UTC +1)`. I then need to compare this with a list of stored headers to work out if the file is valid however my stored headers are used for writing and so allow flexibility on the timezones by being written like so `Time (UTC {0})`.

I would like to know what the best way of dealing with this in as much of a flexible statement as possible. The only way I can imagine doing it is by getting the position of the { and only comparing up to that. This is fine in this circumstance but what if I have some words after the parameter which are more important than a closing bracket.

EDIT: I would like to give some context to the problem so that I can explain better how flexible I need it. I think I possibly didn't emphasise the fact that I didn't want it to JUST work with the time field.

I am trying to write a system which is very flexible. I store a list of valid headings and then use them to find out what value to read/write to the csv file. It is very flexible and easily maintainable. I want to be able to keep it neat and flexible. I want to be able to write a function which takes in a string which has one of more parameters in it and then compare it with a value which has had the parameters filled in (Like the example with the Time header). In the future I may have a field for temperature in a particular place so my stored heading would be `Temperature in {0}({1})` which when I am reading back it would be `Temperature in Britain(c)` or `Temperature in America(f)`.

Comment: have you looked into regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex like this one :

```
string pattern = @"Time \(UTC \{(\+)*\d\}\)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
```

[Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) has a Match method you can use to check whether any string matches the pattern you provided.

Comment: That regular expression would not recognise `Time (UTC +1)` and `Time (UTC {0})` as being the same thing. I did think about using Regex however I believe that in order to make one which would work against any string which has any parameters or even multiple parameters would be too complicated and intensive.

Comment: it's easy to fix the regex to match +1 on top of 0 (I just did it). Generally speaking, regex are the solution to your problem!

Comment: I think I have to do it the hard way and make this code bulkier like you said. Would you be able to help make it flexible though? I have two fields at the moment a `Time (UTC {0})` and a `Time Uploaded (UTC {0})` I need a single statement which will work for both where I could have a method which will take in the version with the parameters filled in an a version with them as {0} and be able to find a match.

Comment: you can add Uploaded to your regex, and use the * operator to specify it can appear zero or multiple times, it would match both your scenarios.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. It would be great if I could get a nice solution to work with any extra fields I add in the future but in theory it should just be these two which have parameters. I am refactoring some really unmaintainable code so I was trying not too add too many things like regex because it is less future proof if we change anything.